# Why isn't the compiler flashing any error?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
int a1[][3]={{1,2,3,4,5,6},{4,5,6,5}};

int (*q)[3];

q=a1;
```

`q` is a pointer to an array of 3 integers. But `a1` does not comply with `q`'s type. Yet the assignment works and no error comes.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Would it be OK if the compiler printed a message instead of flashing?

Comment: Which compiler? Pointer to pointer should be `int **p` irrc.

Comment: Because it's complying with you.

Comment: it shows a warning. But when two types dont match shudn't it be an error?

Comment: @CHID: That probably depends on your compiler's error level settings... You can configure how "sensitive" it is with regards to warning you about these things. It's usually a good idea to crank that all the way up.

Comment: @CHID: DevC++ doesn't have a compiler. Some were bundled with EXTREMELY OLD and EXTREMELY POOR versions of MinGW though...

Comment: I think DevC++ itself is pretty much abandonware these days, isn't it? Code::Blocks seems to be a much better choice.

Comment: @Fred Larson:  Neither Dev-C++ nor Code::Blocks are compilers, both are IDEs; both are available packaged with MinGW/GCC.

Comment: @Billy O'Neil: To be fair, the last release of Dev-C++ was in 2005 and was packaged with MinGW/GCC 3.4.5, that is not really *that* old, and includes most of the C99 support.  GCC 4.x primarily concentrated on improvements to optimisation. I don't think you miss much by using 3.4.5, but Dev-C++ itself still sucks, mostly due to minimal and broken GDB integration.

Comment: @Clifford: I know that. I was referring to the IDE, not the compiler.

Comment: @Fred: But Dev-C++ mentioned was in response to "Which compiler?", so suggesting another different IDE was somewhat off-topic perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types do comply.  `a1` is an array of length-3 arrays of ints.  `q` is a pointer to a length-3 array of ints.  An array decays to a pointer in most circumstances; this is one of them, so everything's fine!

Comment: thank you oli. got the logic. i was thinking in a different angle

Comment: but oli, lik wat u said if                                          int a1[][3]={{1,2,3,5,7,8},{4,5,6,8,9},{1,2},{5,6}}; still it works fine?

Answer (score 2):

See the [C faq on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html). Specifically, [Question 6.2](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the address of the first element of `a1` to the pointer `q`.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. But expressions involving arrays often degenerate into pointers.

Comment: @Fred: This is true -- but I feel compelled to scream about this due to the massive number of people who get things wrong because they assume arrays are pointers. (i.e. assuming int [][] can be pointed to by int **)

Comment: @Billy: I do know that; I missworded my answer. As I remember, arrays are stored as a pointer to the first element, and accessed with arithmetic on the arguments to the [] operator?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Absolutely. I was just typing my comment at the same time you were typing yours. I had no intention of suggesting anything about your comment.

Comment: @Michael: Only when the array is a function argument. Treating them as the same fails when you have multidimensional arrays. (myArray[2][3] is a single block of 6 integers, not an array of two pointers to arrays of length 2) Arrays can implicitly decay into pointers to their first element, but that doesn't mean that they ARE a pointer to their first element.

Comment: @Billy: I understand the first. [][] does NOT mean two pointers. With a pointer to the first element, you can get to any element by: `p + (width * x) + y`. My confusion is about the internal representation of an array declaration. Is it a pointer with some additional information on it or what, then?

Comment: @Michael: Oh, no, no pointers ever enter the picture. The array is just put somewhere on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The types are equvalent - when you use `a1` in the assignment statement it turns into a pointer, and presto - matching types.

Lots more information:

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html